# Extract a whole word from string In Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

for example I have a String text like : "I have to go to the kitchen"
and If I searched this text using the 'av' phrase I want a way that return me the whole word 'have'
how I can do this in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your string into array by space char (" "), and return component that contains your 'av' string.

Answer (score 5):

There is very nice solution with `filter` in swift.You can use `rangeOfString` method of `String` with `filter` to get only filtered string having "av"

```
var s = "I have to go to the kitchen"
//will return "have"
let abc:[String] =  s.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter({ $0.rangeOfString("av", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil } )
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an API for that, [`enumerateSubstrings(in:options:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstrings)

The `byWords` option returns all words in the closure

```
let string = "I have to go to the kitchen"

    var found : String?
    string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { substring, _, _, stop in
        if let word = substring, word.contains("av") {
            found = word
            stop = true
        }
    }
    print(found ?? "not found")
```

Comment: This is much better than the other solutions, because this works with newlines and the others won't (probably also tabs wouldn't work)

Answer (score 1):

```
let words = stringYouWantToSearchIn.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
for word in words
{
   var range = word.rangeOfString(lastWord)
   if (range != nil)
   {
       //you got what do you want in 'word variable'
       break
   }
}
```